# need to get related ids from pivot table

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

i make a many to many relationship table with Laravel and i use frontend as vuejs. i want to get all my related job category ids into specific person. my models looks like this.

In my Person modal relationship looks like this.

```
public function interests()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(SubCategory::class, 'basic_detail_sub_category', 'basic_detail_id', 'sub_category_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and my Job Category modal looks like this

```
public function basics()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(BasicDetails::class, 'basic_detail_sub_category', 'sub_category_id', 'basic_detail_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

i want to get all related job ids with my person modal.

```
public function getBasicDetails()
{
    return BasicDetails::with(['interests' => function($query) {
        $query->select('sub_category_id')->get();
    }])->latest()->get();
}
```

these all are my backend staff. i use v-autocomplete component for view all my job categories.

```
<v-autocomplete
    v-model="basicDetails.interests"
    :disabled="isUpdating"
    :items="interestSub"
    outlined
    item-text="sub_category"
    item-value="id"
    multiple
>
    <template v-slot:selection="data">
     <v-chip
     v-bind="data.attrs"
     :input-value="data.selected"
     close
     @click="data.select"
     @click:close="remove(data.item)"
    >
    {{ data.item.sub_category }}
    </v-chip>
     </template>
     <template v-slot:item="data">
         <template v-if="typeof data.item !== 'object'">
          <v-list-item-content
            v-text="data.item"
          ></v-list-item-content>
         </template>
       <template v-else>
         <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title
               v-html="data.item.sub_category"
            ></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
       </template>
      </template>
    </v-autocomplete>
```

i need to get all related ids from job category table as a array not like all rows in table. how can i achieve this thing? simply i want to get all related job categories and show it on my autocomplete. i used vuex getters to get my details.

```
interestSub(state) {
  return state.interestSub;
 },
```

interest array data shows like this.

```
interests: [
   {
     pivot: Object,
     sub_category_id: 2
   },
   {
     pivot: Object,
     sub_category_id: 1
   },
]
```

but i want to get interests array like this.

```
 interests: [1, 2];
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Laravel Documentation:

Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns

For example, let's assume our User object has many Role objects that it is related to. After accessing this relationship, we may access the intermediate table using the pivot attribute on the models:

```
$user = App\Models\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->pivot->created_at;
}
```

You can obtain obtain the relationships, filter them as you want and then get the pivot fields.

Comment: i want to get only related ids using modal with relation i mentioned in my belongsToMany.

Comment: return BasicDetails::with(['interests' => function($query) {
            $query->select('sub_category_id')->get();
        }])->latest()->get();

Comment: like this with function

Comment: @K.Mihiranga You need to clarify the question. Do you want all subcategories id's from one person and then show them in autocomplete is that?

Comment: i want to get subcategory ids related on that person and only get like a array for sync function in pivot table.

Comment: now my pivot table data shows as an object. but i want to get only pivot ids in that object as a array like this roleIds

Comment: $roleIds = [1, 2];
$user->roles()->sync($roleIds);

Comment: i updated my question how my array shows and how i want to get my array like

Comment: $sub_category_ids = $person->interests->pluck('sub_category_id')